# How do I match a filename without quotes to a name with quotes?

Tags: regex, string, powershell, conditional-statements

*If somebody knows a better title, please do tell me.*

Given these examples:

Three files called: `Jacobs.Ladder.txt`, `Emma.Unplugged.2020.txt` & `Emma.txt`

Three folders called: `Jacobs.Ladder.2019`, `Emma.Unplugged` & `Emma`

Three database-entries called: `Jacob's Ladder`, `Emma: Unplugged` & `Emma`

My PowerShell script is presented with the file, then needs to find the right folder, copy it there, then find the entry in the database and update it there. I need a script that catches all three cases.

So far, what I've done is this:

I take the file's `BaseName` property:

`Jacobs.Ladder`, `Emma.Unplugged`, `Emma`

I use `Get-ChildItem` to put all directories in a variable, do:

`$Directories | Where-Object -Property 'Name' -Contains $File.BaseName`

This finds **exact** matches, so it will only find the folder `Emma`

Next, if nothing was found, I do:

`$Directories | Where-Object -Property 'Name' -Like ('{0}*' -f $File.BaseName)`

This finds the folder `Jacobs.Ladder.2019`. It has already found `Emma` in the previous step, so that has been handled. It will **not** however, find `Emma.Unplugged` because the file's BaseName is `Emma.Unplugged.2020`.

**So that's my first challenge/question: how do I write a conditional that matches `Emma.Unplugged.2020` to `Emma.Unplugged`?**

Next, to match the file name with the database entries, I start with a `replace` to turn the dots into spaces.

I then search for an almost exact match:

`$Database | Where-Object -Property 'Name' -Like $FileNameWithSpaces.Replace(' ','*')`

*I know, I could have just replaced the dots with asterisks. But I don't know yet if the name with spaces is going to be useful somewhere else.*

Although this does compensate for the colon in `Emma.Unplugged`,  this once again only finds `Emma`.

**There is my second challenge: how do I form my query to match (again) `Emma.Unplugged.2020` to `Emma: Unplugged` but also `Jacobs.Ladder` to `Jacob's Ladder`?**

Of course, if you can think of more scenarios that I didn't catch here, feel free to add those in your code.

As for the topic title, my biggest challenge is that single quote in the word. Right now the best way I can think of is if I on-the-fly turn all database-names into their filename equivalent. Then `Jacob's Ladder` would become `Jacobs.Ladder` and I would have a match. Which would leave the 2020 as my biggest challenge.

Comment: You could, for the purpose of comparison, use a set of transformation rules on file, folder and database identifiers to make them comparable. For example: 1) remove all non-letter characters, 2) make all letters lowercase. That would get you `jacobsladder` for each of `Jacobs.Ladder`, `Jacobs.Ladder.2019` and `Jacob's Ladder` which you can use for matching them up. Then you use the orginal names for file and database operations.

Comment: I have been playing with that idea since I posted that last paragraph. It's not the most efficient solution to have to transform all three, but maybe it is the best. Of course, I would be remiss if I didn't mention there was also a `Jacobs.Ladder.US.txt`.

Comment: Sure, you'd have to find a set of transformations that suit your problem; you could also shorten strings to compare only the first ten characters or drop substrings that are below a certain treshhold. It's not ideal, but then neither is matching identifiers from three different sources. :)